# Wiris Math Formula as Base64 SVG image is not rendered correctly in MS Edge

Tags: svg, base64, microsoft-edge, wiris

The following base64 SVG image is not rendered correctly in Microsoft Edge.
In other browsers this works perfectly.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img align="middle" 
         class="Wirisformula fr-fic fr-dii fr-draggable" 
         style="max-width: none;" 
         alt="integral subscript 0 superscript t space open parentheses x squared plus 1 third close parentheses space straight d x space equals negative 2" 
         src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOndycz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53aXJpcy5jb20veG1sL2N2cy1leHRlbnNpb24iIGhlaWdodD0iNDgiIHdpZHRoPSIxNTYiIHdyczpiYXNlbGluZT0iMjkiPjwhLS1NYXRoTUw6IDxtYXRoIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk4L01hdGgvTWF0aE1MIj48bXN1YnN1cD48bW8%2BJiN4MjIyQjs8L21vPjxtbj4wPC9tbj48bWk%2BdDwvbWk%2BPC9tc3Vic3VwPjxtbz4mI3hBMDs8L21vPjxtZmVuY2VkPjxtcm93Pjxtc3VwPjxtaT54PC9taT48bW4%2BMjwvbW4%2BPC9tc3VwPjxtbz4rPC9tbz48bWZyYWM%2BPG1uPjE8L21uPjxtbj4zPC9tbj48L21mcmFjPjwvbXJvdz48L21mZW5jZWQ%2BPG1vPiYjeEEwOzwvbW8%2BPG1pIG1hdGh2YXJpYW50PSJub3JtYWwiPmQ8L21pPjxtaT54PC9taT48bW8%2BJiN4QTA7PC9tbz48bW8%2BPTwvbW8%2BPG1vPi08L21vPjxtbj4yPC9tbj48L21hdGg%2BLS0%2BPGRlZnM%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%2BPC9kZWZzPjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJtYXRoMTYxYTM3ODFmMzg4YzY0NjVhYmY3NzFmNTQ1IiBmb250LXNpemU9IjMyIiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSI4LjUiIHk9IjMzIj4mI3gyMjJCOzwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTIiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjE0LjUiIHk9IjQ0Ij4wPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJBcmlhbCIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxMiIgZm9udC1zdHlsZT0iaXRhbGljIiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSIxOS41IiB5PSIxMSI%2BdDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iYnJhY2tldHNlNTUyZjU0MTdmZjQ2ODBjNmI1MDQ5OSIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxNiIgdGV4dC1hbmNob3I9InN0YXJ0IiB4PSIyNy41IiB5PSIxOCI%2BJiN4MjM5Qjs8L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9ImJyYWNrX3NtMjg4MmFkNjA1YjFlMjdiZTg3Yzc0NjgiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJzdGFydCIgeD0iMjcuNSIgeT0iMjMiPiYjeDIzOUM7PC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJicmFja19zbTI4ODJhZDYwNWIxZTI3YmU4N2M3NDY4IiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ic3RhcnQiIHg9IjI3LjUiIHk9IjI4Ij4mI3gyMzlDOzwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iYnJhY2tldHNlNTUyZjU0MTdmZjQ2ODBjNmI1MDQ5OSIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxNiIgdGV4dC1hbmNob3I9InN0YXJ0IiB4PSIyNy41IiB5PSI0MiI%2BJiN4MjM5RDs8L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9ImJyYWNrZXRzZTU1MmY1NDE3ZmY0NjgwYzZiNTA0OTkiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJzdGFydCIgeD0iODIuNSIgeT0iMTgiPiYjeDIzOUU7PC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJicmFja19zbTI4ODJhZDYwNWIxZTI3YmU4N2M3NDY4IiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ic3RhcnQiIHg9IjgyLjUiIHk9IjIzIj4mI3gyMzlGOzwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iYnJhY2tfc20yODgyYWQ2MDViMWUyN2JlODdjNzQ2OCIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxNiIgdGV4dC1hbmNob3I9InN0YXJ0IiB4PSI4Mi41IiB5PSIyOCI%2BJiN4MjM5Rjs8L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9ImJyYWNrZXRzZTU1MmY1NDE3ZmY0NjgwYzZiNTA0OTkiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJzdGFydCIgeD0iODIuNSIgeT0iNDIiPiYjeDIzQTA7PC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJBcmlhbCIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxNiIgZm9udC1zdHlsZT0iaXRhbGljIiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSIzNy41IiB5PSIyOSI%2BeDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTIiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1LjUiIHk9IjIyIj4yPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJtYXRoMTYxYTM3ODFmMzg4YzY0NjVhYmY3NzFmNTQ1IiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSI1Ni41IiB5PSIyOSI%2BKzwvdGV4dD48bGluZSBzdHJva2U9IiMwMDAwMDAiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lY2FwPSJzcXVhcmUiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMSIgeDE9IjY2LjUiIHgyPSI3OC41IiB5MT0iMjMuNSIgeTI9IjIzLjUiLz48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjcyLjUiIHk9IjE4Ij4xPC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJBcmlhbCIgZm9udC1zaXplPSIxNiIgdGV4dC1hbmNob3I9Im1pZGRsZSIgeD0iNzIuNSIgeT0iNDAiPjM8L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9IkFyaWFsIiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSI5Ni41IiB5PSIyOSI%2BZDwvdGV4dD48dGV4dCBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIGZvbnQtc3R5bGU9Iml0YWxpYyIgdGV4dC1hbmNob3I9Im1pZGRsZSIgeD0iMTA1LjUiIHk9IjI5Ij54PC90ZXh0Pjx0ZXh0IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJtYXRoMTYxYTM3ODFmMzg4YzY0NjVhYmY3NzFmNTQ1IiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSIxMjIuNSIgeT0iMjkiPj08L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9Im1hdGgxNjFhMzc4MWYzODhjNjQ2NWFiZjc3MWY1NDUiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMTYiIHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjEzOC41IiB5PSIyOSI%2BJiN4MjIxMjs8L3RleHQ%2BPHRleHQgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9IkFyaWFsIiBmb250LXNpemU9IjE2IiB0ZXh0LWFuY2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSIxNTAuNSIgeT0iMjkiPjI8L3RleHQ%2BPC9zdmc%2B" 
         data-mathml="«math xmlns=¨http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML¨»«msubsup»«mo»§#8747;«/mo»«mn»0«/mn»«mi»t«/mi»«/msubsup»«mo»§#160;«/mo»«mfenced»«mrow»«msup»«mi»x«/mi»«mn»2«/mn»«/msup»«mo»+«/mo»«mfrac»«mn»1«/mn»«mn»3«/mn»«/mfrac»«/mrow»«/mfenced»«mo»§#160;«/mo»«mi mathvariant=¨normal¨»d«/mi»«mi»x«/mi»«mo»§#160;«/mo»«mo»=«/mo»«mo»-«/mo»«mn»2«/mn»«/math»">
</body>
</html>
```

*in Chrome / Firefox / IE*

[image: As it should be!]

*In Edge*

[image: Totally FUBAR]

**extra information**

- The SVG is constructed with the [Froala Editor with the 3rd party Wiris plug-in enabled](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/wiris).
- This problem occurs in the old (pre-chromium, Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0) version of Microsoft Edge. Updating is not an option.

Comment: If you try the same mathematical expression in the [official demo](http://www.wiris.com/plugins/demo/froala/aspx/), it also won't work in Edge. So I think the issue is with wiris math formula compatibility with Edge browser. You could try to contact wiris to fix the issue.

Comment: I already did. The wiris developers are looking into it.
I'll update the question when I hear back from them and/or if the issue is fixed.